# How to produce the mainline kernel .config file from the mainline-crack repository?

Tags: kernel, compiling, configuration

I wanted to produce a .config file equal to the mainline kernel configuration.

Based on my understanding, I can create that from the mainline-crack repository (git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel-test/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/mainline-crack).

However, when I try to produce a configuration (from my host, which is an amd64), it still differs from the config I find under /boot when I run a kernel installed from the mainline PPA.

I've tried in different ways, for example:

```sh
git clone git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel-test/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/mainline-crack
cd mainline-crack
git checkout cod/mainline/v6.0.3
make defconfig
```

the resulting file is relatively small (130k), and after compiling and installing, the system doesn't even boot.

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to run a kernel that has not be tested for use with Ubuntu?

Comment: That's not relevant to the question. But anyway, there are multiple valid cases (e.g. hardware support); additionally, producing the configuration of a Canonical kernel does not imply building and using that kernel, as the configuration can be built on a different (e.g. vanilla) kernel.